# Parse Android: Parse UI Login with Layout Override

Tags: android, xml, parse-platform

I would like to use the ParseLoginUI library with the layout override so I can login using custom layouts. I'm not having much luck and the documentation isn't helping much either. I'm following [this tutorial on Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#ui-login)

Here is my login layout, **com_parse_ui_parse_login_fragment.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:background="#EBEBEB">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/splash"
        android:src="@drawable/beam_splash"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/login_username_input"
        style="@style/ParseLoginUI.EditText"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/login_password_input"
        style="@style/ParseLoginUI.EditText"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_username_input"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/ParseLoginUI.Button"
        android:text="Login"
        android:background="#2DC4DE"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/parse_login_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_password_input"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/login_password_input"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/login_password_input" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/twitter_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/ParseLoginUI.Button.ThirdPartyLogin"
        android:background="@drawable/com_parse_ui_twitter_login_button_background_selector"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/com_parse_ui_twitter_login_logo"
        android:text="Login With Twitter"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/parse_login_button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        style="@style/ParseLoginUI.Button"
        android:background="#2DC4DE"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/parse_signup_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/twitter_login"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/login_password_input"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/login_password_input" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.harmonicvibration.beam" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".BeamApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity.PARSE_LOGIN_ENABLED"
                android:value="true"/>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity.TWITTER_LOGIN_ENABLED"
                android:value="true"/>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
                android:value="@string/parse_app_id" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
                android:value="@string/parse_client_key" />

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Only the Twitter login button is responsive. I am expecting that when I click Login or Sign-up, it will try to login or take me to the signup page (I have created a com_parse_ui_parse_signup_fragment.xml file) but I'm assuming I missed a crucial step.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you found the solution of the above problem?

Comment: I have not. I ended up just using the uncustomized login page

Comment: So you are using parse login page as it is.

Comment: Did you tried to use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout?